# First run of parallel for_each is 10x times slower

Tags: c++, linux, performance, gcc, c++17

I have some proprietary code that basically executes a triple for loop. Which I have decided to speedup, by moving one of the loops into `std::for_each` construct with `std::execution::par_unseq` policy.

The code updates some shared std::vector, which is now protected by a mutexed lock. The code has no static local variables.

```
std::vector<OutputType>
Detector::Detect(
    const std::vector<Points>& path,
    const std::vector<Object>& objects) const {
    std::vector<OutputType> hits;
    std::mutex mtx;

        std::for_each (std::execution::par_unseq,
        objects.cbegin(),
        objects.cend(),
        [&](auto const& obj){
            std::set<ObjectId> already_hit;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i) {
                if (already_hit.contains(obj.id_)) {
                    continue;
                }
                for (size_t j = 0; j < obj.convex_hull.size(); ++j) {
                    auto pt = CalcThings(path[i], obj.convex_hull[j]),;
                    if (Condition(pt, path[i])) {
                        {
                            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                            hits.emplace_back(OutputType(path[i], obj.id_));
                        }
                        already_hit.insert(obj.id_);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    return hits;
}
```

I have a driver code, that runs the code under inspection and measures time of the execution. To remove doubts, that tic and toc brings some statics initialization into the story, I have called to the pair just before the for

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        FrameContent content = ReadNextFrame();

        if (content.valid) {
            Detector detector(args);

            {
                tic(0, "detector_name", content.path.size(),
                    content.objects.size());

                detector.Detect(content.path, content.objects);

                toc();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the output saved into file looks pretty strange, as the first run takes considerably more time:

| detector | ns | # pts | # objs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| let_statics_waste_time | 190 | 0 | 0 |
| detector_name | 4400605 | 655 | 41 |
| detector_name | 538334 | 609 | 41 |
| detector_name | 494972 | 645 | 41 |
| detector_name | 435749 | 643 | 44 |
| detector_name | 408687 | 608 | 44 |
| detector_name | 398247 | 637 | 41 |
| detector_name | 387577 | 644 | 43 |
| detector_name | 382989 | 626 | 45 |
| detector_name | 396695 | 655 | 44 |
| detector_name | 368802 | 604 | 41 |
| detector_name | 379612 | 606 | 41 |
| detector_name | 377248 | 602 | 43 |
| detector_name | 382789 | 604 | 43 |
| detector_name | 418576 | 679 | 43 |
| detector_name | 392887 | 609 | 47 |
| detector_name | 490854 | 608 | 49 |
| detector_name | 413126 | 605 | 48 |
| detector_name | 456449 | 678 | 51 |
| detector_name | 466518 | 664 | 46 |
| detector_name | 428225 | 643 | 43 |
| detector_name | 378280 | 607 | 46 |
| detector_name | 392197 | 624 | 50 |
| detector_name | 401313 | 641 | 43 |
| detector_name | 448904 | 681 | 45 |
| detector_name | 421893 | 643 | 45 |
| detector_name | 446910 | 682 | 42 |
| detector_name | 491936 | 678 | 46 |

What bothers me a lot, is the huge [order of magnitude] higher run-time of the first frame. Which is by no means special from the POV of data in it.

Why is this happens? Is it some caching of virtual tables (Detector is a class implementing an interface with `override`)?

Comment: Maybe the first run creates the thread pool?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, is there a way to forcibly init before the runs?

Comment: Don't lock/unlock in a tight loop. This won't fix the issue you're asking about here, but it will avoid thread convoys. Those happen when a lock is used in a high frequency by multiple threads. If ever one thread blocks with the lock held (e.g. when reallocating the vector), other threads will queue up on the lock. If the first one now runs again it will release the lock and, if it tries to lock it again, it will also be locked. In the end, it stalls throughput due to an avalance of context switches. Instead, collect the results of each thread and combine them in the end.

Comment: Unsure, try running some arbitrary parallel algorithm once before the benchmark?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, this is the next idea to try. However, it is not the issue here, as other frames execute exactly the same code, with exactly the same pitfalls

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I think you should make it an answer, I have added simple for_each to update a vector in parallel, and it cut the time 3 times, enlarging the vector cuts it further 2 times. So it is the thread creation overhead.

Comment: I'm ok with you posting it.

Comment: Next time, post the compiler and compiler options used to build the program.  The most important of these options are the optimization settings used.  If you are timing a "debug" or unoptimized build, the timings you are showing are basically meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @HolyBlackCat, the issue seems to be a ThreadPool initialization.

I have added a simple:

```
void TryInitializeTheThreadPool(){
    std::vector<int> nums(10000);
    for(auto i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
        nums[i] = i;
    }

    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, nums.begin(), nums.end(),
        [](auto& n){ n *= 2; });
}
```

and the results were as follows (note, below entries are for 100'000 and 1'000'000 elements in the vector)

| detector | ns | # pts | # objs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| detector_name(vec size 10'000) | 1361699 | 655 | 41 |
| detector_name(vec size 100'000) | 776356 | 655 | 41 |
| detector_name(vec size 1'000'000) | 699039 | 655 | 41 |

I suppose, the first try did create a number of threads, but more were needed, hence an additional time cut could have been achieved.